# Connecting to API issues

Tags: python, rest, api

I am new to Python and am trying to use it to connect to Americommerce API. They have an example on git. 
It doesn't seem to work though. I add the url to STORE_DOMAIN, key to ACCESS_TOKEN, and app id to STORE_ID.

The only one that seems to matter is the web url. If I mispell it I get coonection errors, however the key and id I can enter whatever I want there and get the same results. here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# The 'requests' module is available via pip: "pip install requests"
# You can find more documentation about requests at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/
import requests
import json
import locale
import sys

STORE_DOMAIN = "http://www.example.com"
ACCESS_TOKEN = "key"
STORE_ID = "app_id"  # This should reflect your store's ID

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

# Searches for and returns the customer that matches the info passed in,
# if no customer is found a new one is created and returned
def get_customer(firstName, lastName, email):

    # setup headers
    headers = {
        'X-AC-Auth-Token': ACCESS_TOKEN,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    # build API call to check if customer already exists (using email)
    uri = '{}/api/v1/customers?email={}'.format(STORE_DOMAIN, email)

    # include verify=False if using dev certificate
    # r = requests.get(uri, headers = headers, verify=False)
    r = requests.get(uri, headers = headers)

    # see if a customer was found
    customer = r.json()
    if (customer['total_count'] > 0):
        return customer['customers'][0]

    # no customer found, so lets create a new one
    data = {
        'last_name': doe,
        'first_name': john,
        'email': johndoe@email.com,
        'store_id': 4
    }

    # build API call to post a new customer
    uri = '{}/api/v1/customers'.format(STORE_DOMAIN)

    # include verify=False if using dev certificate
    # r = requests.post(uri, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(data), verify=False)
    r = requests.post(uri, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(data))

    # return newly created customer
    return r.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    customer = get_customer('John', 'Doe', 'JohnDoe@email.com')
    first_name = customer['first_name'].encode('utf-8')
    last_name = ',{}\n'.format(customer['last_name']).encode('utf-8')
    email = customer['email'].encode('utf-8')
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(first_name + last_name + email)
```

I get this result when I run this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getStuff.py", line 57, in <module>
    customer = get_customer('John', 'Doe', 'JohnDoe@email.com')
  File "./getStuff.py", line 35, in get_customer
    if (customer['total_count'] > 0):
KeyError: 'total_count'
```

Please, a little help here would be appreciated. Ive been stuck on this for a bit now.

Comment: You haven't shown what the JSON response actually is - have you used `print(r.json())` to see what the API sends back?

Comment: First of all, `print(customer)` to see what it contains. If it doesn't contain what you want, then you're using the API the wrong way and should consult its docs.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting key error because your dictionary/JOSN `customer` does not contain key `total_count`